# VPN only connects once and then fails

Tags: windows-vista, router, vpn

I have a VPN connection setup to my office from home, it works great except for one thing.  Once I connect and then disconnect the next time I go to connect to the vpn it hangs on verifying your username and password.  No matter how many times I try.

Once I restart my router it works again.

My router is a belkin, the router on the other end is a Draytek.

Any ideas?  Is there a cache somewhere that needs to be reset, a setting?

I'm on Windows Vista, but I dont think its an issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a free software guy, i have a VPN on my office, i use OpenVpn and it works quite well.

The only thing i do is to redirect incoming traffic on port 1194 to the openvpn server and that's it.

Hope it helps.